# Удаление дублей строк в результате парсинга

Tags: python

Часть кода.

```
 with open("parse.txt", "a") as file:
        if file.tell():
         file.write('\n')    
    file.write('\n'.join(map(str, (item.get("Id") for item in x if item.get("Id")))))

    with open("parse.txt") as input_:
        result = dict.fromkeys(input_).keys()
    
    with open("parse.txt", "w") as output:
        print(*result, file=output, sep="")
```

Я не уверен что правильно использую witch open. Как следует оптимизировать код чтобы не обращаться к файлу несколько раз?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какое отношение заголовок имеет к вопросу.

Comment: в вопросе я использую  result = dict.fromkeys(input_).keys() для удаления дублей, но не знаю правильно ли  использую with open  в данном случае.

Comment: Использование with open, хоть правильное, хоть неправильное, вообще не имеет никакого отношения к удалению дубликатов.

Comment: подскажете как правильно удалить дубликаты?

Comment: Откуда их нужно удалить?

Comment: после того как выполнится    file.write('\n'.join(map(str, (item.get("Id") for item in x if item.get("Id")))))  нужно удалить дубли и записать в файл parse.txt

Comment: Читаете файл в список. Удаляете дубликаты. Сохраняете результат.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обьясните как это сделать второй день голову ломаю получается только через костыли..

Comment: Ну смотрите, задача чуть ли не стандартная. Вы же не первый, кому такое потребовалось. Попробуйте поискать решение, обычно с этого начинают. Даже на этой странице с вопросом явижу несколько ссылок на похожие заголовки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, этот вариант кода делает то, что вам нужно?

```
with open("parse.txt", "a+") as file:
    if file.tell():
        file.write('\n')    
    file.write('\n'.join(map(str, (item.get("Id") for item in x if item.get("Id")))))
    file.seek(0)  # Не уверен, что это здесь надо, протестируйте
    result = dict.fromkeys(file).keys()
    file.seek(0)  # Здесь тоже
    print(*result, file=file, sep="")
```

Comment: Строки записываются 2 раза, оставляя дубли.Без обоих file.seek   строки записываются 1 раз, но дубли по прежнему не удаляет.

Comment: @bauna28, попробуйте убрать print в конце